# Invalid argument in DAO.Recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am facing a minor issue that I just can't seem to wrap my head around.
Instead of using SQL, I want to check for duplicates between two tables using vba.
So, what I did was create two recordsets. One for each table, and simply check if I can find the Document Number in the one recordset, while looping through the other.

The error I get each time is in the .FindFirst line. It tells me that I am using an invalid argument. (Error 3001). rscurrent![Document Number] Always returns a number.
I have tried to do it by dimming a string and double but neither seems to work.

Am I using a whole wrong way of thinking here, or am I just missing some syntax? And again, I know how to do this in SQL, this is more to satisfy my own curiosity regarding vba and to check for possible performance improvements.

Anyhow, Thanks in advance!

```
Sub comparemails()
Dim rscurrent As DAO.Recordset
Dim rscheck As DAO.Recordset

Set rscurrent = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tbl_DNFAILURE", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rscheck = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tbl_Archive", dbOpenDynaset)

With rscurrent
    Do Until .EOF
            With rscheck
                .MoveFirst
                .FindFirst rscurrent![Document Number]
                    If .NoMatch = False Then
                        rscurrent.Delete
                    End If
            End With
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

rscurrent.Close
rscheck.Close
Set rscurrent = Nothing
Set rscheck = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: See the documentation of `RecordSet.FindFirst`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/ff194787%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FindFirst requires a string to locate the record. It is like the WHERE clause in an SQL statement, but without the word WHERE.

For example:

```
rstEmployees.FindFirst "Age > 30"
```

Your code doesn't say which field it should match rscurrent![Document Number] with. You would have to have something like

```
.FindFirst "DocumentNumber = " & rscurrent![Document Number]
```

Comment: Aah ofcourse! Such a basic mistake! Thank you very much!